# UFT error "Run stopped by user." and skips input sheet in case of 2 failed scenarios

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I am new to UFT.
I have input excel sheet which contains list of scenarios.
In my code I iterate through this excel and run scenarios one by one.
When all the scenarios are running successfully it processes entire sheet.
But when any 2 scenarios fail it skips remaining sheet.
In Test Flow it gives error "Run stopped by user.".
Has anyone faced this issue? I am not using any explicit ExitIteration based on scenario execution status.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you execute your tests? (Local Machine, remote machine)

Comment: on remote machine

Comment: be sure that the remote machine does not lock. If i connect to my remote machines via RDP the machine locks after 30 minutes and all tests running on this machine will get this error. 
Try to execute the tests on a local machine.

Comment: No,machine doesn't get locked,

Comment: can you post an screenshot from the report?

Comment: I debugged the code, this happened because of "ExitActionIteration" statement. I commented it ,and now its running fine. Thanks for all the replies.